# Angular (latest): How to detect if Component is loaded via Router or Selector?

Tags: angular

Assuming I have `PageComponent` and it's accessible via a Selector and also in the Router as a Route, how can I tell if the Component is loaded via the selector `<page-component>` or by the `<router-outlet>`?

I found a hacky way of passing an attribute like this: `@Input('viaSelector') viaSelector: boolean = false;` and then `<page-component [viaSelector]="true"></page-component>`.

But is there something native that I can use to detect how a Component is loaded?!

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter when you are loading it via a route.
if paramMap for route has that parameter available and is a valid parameter, you know it is loaded from route. If the parameter is null, you know is it loaded from selector.

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.get('yourparameter'));
})
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to my current hacky method using the `@Input` so I tell myself it was loaded via selector? Technically, I have it already figured out in this "un-official" way. I was wondering if anything is provided internally so I can say: `isViaRouter` or `isViaSelector` since Angular knows (I hope) if it loaded something as result of a Tag or a Router event...

Comment: That is actually a good and a route way unless you want to keep a flag in the service or a variable in localstorage (or sessionstorage)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to check if the component matches the one assigned to the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#component):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-kal424?file=app/views/foo/foo.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  template: '<h3>{{ compSource }}</h3>',
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  compSource = '';

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.route.component === this.constructor) {
      this.compSource = 'loaded by route';
    } else {
      this.compSource = 'loaded by selector';
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we can only compare against the component constructor (aka "class"), not the instance. This is fine for most use cases, but it won't work if you have nested instances of the same component.

Comment: This looks like the only solution, and for recursive components one could add a parameter to distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at Angular lifecycle hooks.
By loaded what do you mean? Is the view loaded? Did the component got initialized?

The most common ones that I usually use are:

- **ngOnInit**, as cited from the angular official docs:

> Initialize the directive or component after Angular first displays the
> data-bound properties and sets the directive or component's input
> properties.

- **ngAfterViewInit**:

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
> views, or the view that contains the directive.

For more information about life cycle hooks checkout this [link](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: I'm new to Angular and might not be using the right Angular wording but the thing is definitely already loaded when I want to know how it was done: via `<my-component></my-component>` or `{ path: 'route/path', component: MyComponent }`.